# JTable issue can't getting content of main columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I try to get result like this:

[image]

But "il","plaka kodu","bölge" does not appear.
I couldn't find where did i miss.
I did enter JTable parameters but it does not show up.

Here is my code:

```
public jp_10() {
    super("JTable");

    Container con = getContentPane();
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    Object sutun[] = { "İl", "Plaka Kodu", "Bölge"};
    Object satır[][] = { { "İzmir", "35", "Karşıyaka" },
            { "İstanbul", "34", "Beykoz" }, { "Bursa", "16", "Camlık" } };

    tablo = new JTable(satır, sutun);
    con.add(tablo);

    tablo.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    ListSelectionModel model = tablo.getSelectionModel();
    model.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    model.addListSelectionListener(this);

    etiket1 = new JLabel("Seçilen veri: ");
    con.add(etiket1);

    etiket2 = new JLabel();
    con.add(etiket2);
    setSize(500,200);
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    int sutunIndis = tablo.getSelectedColumn();
    int satirIndis = tablo.getSelectedRow();

    Object seciliEleman;

    seciliEleman = tablo.getValueAt(satirIndis, sutunIndis);
    etiket2.setText(String.valueOf(seciliEleman));
}
```

Comment: Add your table to a scroll pane.

Comment: This is also clearly indicated in the [Add `JTable` to a `Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show) section of the Swing Table tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a table header.

the easiest way to display a table header is to add your `JTable` to a `JScrollPane` first:

```
con.add(new JScrollPane(tablo));
```